# Displaying the Time stamp of files under the workspace in a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-api

I have been looking to find a solution to display the time stamp of files under the workspace of a Jenkins job(open source).

*Figure depicting how it should finally look like:*

[image: Figure depicting how it should finally look like]

The following are the **prior researches** done :

- I searched through the list of Jenkins available plugins and I did not get any of them serving the purpose .
- I have also looked for answers in various forums regarding a similar question but that didn't help either.
- The only answer which came closest to the requirement was discussed here : [patch for adding timestamp](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/cr_ZpR2EMlw).
  But the patch also seems to have some errors when I tried applying the patch from Jenkins as a build parameter.

Are there any such requirement met and solved before? Are there any Jenkins plugins developed for a similar scenario?

If the only option is to develop a **new Jenkins plugin**, how do I start with?

I was trying to get a response of the Jenkins page via **REST API**, but since I am a newbie to the topic I was not able to figure out how to manipulate,edit the workspace page in Jenkins.

So where to begin with and meet my requirements? Any documentation of such scenario or links will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Current LTS **2.138.3** already has such feature(The prior version I installed was **2.121.1**, which didn't). I use CentOS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Jenkins script you should do:

```
file_path = "<directory>"

def file_mod_time = sh(script: "stat -c %Y $file_path", returnStatus: false, returnStdout: true).trim().toLong()
```

This should give you a time stamp in Unix Epoch.

You can then convert this using a new `Date(file_mod_time)` call.